# How can I deploy a single Firebase Cloud Function in a group and a region?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have created a group of Firebase Cloud Functions (`v2`) that are deployed in a region (`europe-west1`).

```
#index.ts
import * as apiV2 from './v2';
export const v2 = apiV2;
```

```
#v2.ts
export const addTextMessage = functions.region('europe-west1').onCall(
 ...
)
```

I want only to deploy the `addTextMessage` function.
I tried:

```sh
firebase deploy --only functions:v2-addTextMessage
# or
firebase deploy --only "functions:v2-addTextMessage(europe-west1)"
```

However the function is not deployed:

```sh
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: current functions in project: v2-addTextMessage(europe-west1)
⚠  functions: the following filters were specified but do not match any functions in the project: v2-addTextMessage(europe-west1)
```

What command should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to replace the "-" by ".".

You should use :

```
firebase deploy --only functions:groupName.functionName
```

In your case :

```
firebase deploy --only functions:v2.addTextMessage
```

It's true that the CLI terminal log is misleading because if you've exceeded your deployment quota and the CLI detects that the name of your function is for instance `v2-addTextMessage(europe-west-1)`, it will print a message suggesting you to use the command `firebase deploy --only functions:v2-addTextMessage` to deploy this function only, which doesn't work.

See the full [Firebase CLI documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct command, however, you have not exported the `addTextMessage` function to your `index.ts` file, without that the deployment cannot find the funtion to deploy. You can export it by adding the following code to your `index.ts`:

```
export const v2-addTextMessage = apiV2.addTextMessage
```

Also, you cannot use the functions parameter and the function name as a String. So your command on this case would have to be:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:v2-addTextMessage
```

For Specifying region on deployment, as you already added to your code on the edited version of the question, you cannot do it on the FirebaseCLI command, thanks to @Doug Stevenson for pointing that out on the comment section.

Ideally, as you can see on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xu5A1seU6PU), you would have to specify that in your cloud function code, before deployment by adding the following:

```
exports.v2-addTextMessage = functions
    .region('europe-west1')
    .storage.object().onFinalize((object) => { });
```

Comment: Deployment doesn't have a `--region` flag.  That's just for deleting a function in a specific region that was deployed to multiple regions.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Thanks, I will edit that part out of the answer, I was looking at this [gcloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy) and assumed it was also applicable for FirebaseCLI.

Comment: This command does not work either. To be more accurate, the function is not called `v2-addTextMessage`. The function is `addTextMessage` is declared in a `v2.ts `file : (`
export const addTextMessage = functions.region('europe-west1').onCall( ....)
`. And the global ìndex.ts` contains: `import * as apiV2 from './api/apiV2'; export const v2 = apiV2;

Comment: So does `firebase deploy --only functions:addTextMessage` not work? Not sure what you meant by index is export, can you clarify?

Comment: My comment is not clear, I have edited the question to show the organization of my functions.

Comment: @windycrazy replace this line `export const v2 = apiV2;` by this `export const addTextMessage = apiV2.addTextMessage`, or simply add it if you need it somewhere else in your code. Then try to deploy using `firebase deploy --only functions:addTextMessage` and let me know if it works

Comment: @ralemos yes it works fine like this. However I would really like to have the v2 group.

Comment: What do you mean by have the v2 group? Deploy the whole group or have the "v2" in the command? You can do the latter it by adding `v2-` to the `export const` mentioned above. Anyway, I will edit the answer to reflect the command above that you confirmed it work, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it sufficiently helped you.

Comment: @windycrazy Is this what you expected? If so, remember to accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: @ralemos Sorry it doesn't work. `const v2-addTextMessage` is not valid javascript.

Comment: what if you lose the `-` on the variable name?